# Can a USB Oscilloscope be used reliably and accurately for RF projects?

Tags: rf, oscilloscope

Are USB based oscilloscopes "sensitive" or able to be used with RF circuits?  In particular, are they able to see the waveforms, carrier wave, etc. of something like a crystal set?

I saw something like these (I picked these a random, first ones I saw),

DigiTech QC-1929 (Hantek 6022BE) USB Oscilloscope

Hantek 100MHz PC Based USB Oscilloscope

The first is much cheaper, but the second is $200 (where I saw it), and that is getting close to a new or used scope.

For context, this is for hobby/enthusiast.  It is also mostly for RF based projects like a Crystal Radio and seeing AM, Shortwave, and the like.

For example, I want to see the carrier wave and the AM modulation and what ends up getting sent to the earpiece, the "information."  That may not be the right terminology.  Hopefully you understand what I want to see.

Comment: Their ability to "see" waveforms depends on their bandwidth and the frequency of interest. Would be silly to sell a scope where 45MHz is within its bandwidth but its allergic to it.

Comment: The problem is not the USB, but that most USB devices are just bad scopes.  The 6022 is horribly crude.  It's more of a streaming data acquisition device than a scope.   It utterly lacks any kind of trigger circuit.   And the analog front end is pretty limited too - you'll likely not see anything but noise in a crystal set.  In fact without amplification you may not with any affordable scope.  For the audio output you can just use a sound card.

Comment: A scope is likely going to be less useful for your efforts than you think, if you do want to get one you might look for a deal on an old analog scope.  Budget priced digital scopes are more suited for digital projects and debugging their analog failings, than they are for low-level analog or radio work.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I guess it might be against the rules to ask, but is there a scope that you recommend for radio and one that I can use for digital?  Or do I get two scopes?

Comment: I don't know much about RF but have very good experience with Picoscope devices. Maybe something in their range would be good for you? Many of them have MSO as an option - that is a logic analyzer included. The interface is clean, quite intuitive and works both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: The lowest pico scope model with actual oscilloscope performance is going to cost more than a traditional modern bench oscilloscope.  It might still be useful for niche applications (portability, data analysis) but for general use a traditional scope is less expensive and more usable.

Comment: You can get decent but old 20MHz analogue scopes on ebay for <$100, and much less if you can find one in person (they're very expensive to ship since they are heavy and fragile).

Comment: Bottom line will be to identify your highest fundamental frequency you want to measure, then select a scope with at least 5x that bandwidth. If it's digital, the sample rate needs to be at least 4x the scope bandwidth. 5x bandwidth allows for wave shape accuracy including 5th order harmonics, and 4x sampling allows for accurate capture of phase and amplitude variation. Sampling rates are split between active channels, so multiply that need by the number of planned scope channels. The rest of the specs, USB or benchtop, all depend on your tolerances and project needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope quality and features has little to do with the interfaces it has. What matters is the specs and the reputation of the brand that allows you to trust these specs.

RF is a little vague, but if you want to clearly see e.g. 100MHz signals, you need a scope with at least 100MHz bandwidth (which will translate to 0,5 to 1 GHz sampling rate). As an example, Hantek 6022BE is advertised as having 48MHz sampling rate, and 20MHz bandwidth, and I'm pretty skeptical about the bandwidth.

Comment: I think I need to ask a different question.  I will try to ask better.

Comment: I think this answer is likely most relevant to the RF-ness of the question.

Comment: The 6022 only even gets those numners if you are okay with a random, untriggered snapshot.

Answer (score 3):

What does one thing have to do with another?  You look at a big expensive scope it is a windows computer with some boards in it for the measurement interfaces as well as the knobs and buttons.  This day and age do we really need that?  Knobs and buttons are superior to touch screens yes, but there is no technical reason why they cant build the same quality scope as far as measurement capability goes.  Being wrapped by a computer display and knobs does not affect the quality of the  measurement for a properly designed scope.  No reason other than profit selling is a computer and buttons at an inflated price, that they cant provide high speed high quality scopes that we connect to via ethernet or usb and run software on a computer we provide.

Being a non-screen, non-button scope does not have anything to do with the potential quality of the measurement.  Nor does having buttons and a screen make a scopes ability to measure and display a signal any better.  A bad scope is bad scope in whatever form factor.  As is a good one.

If your real question is, are these specific products I named any good, I would say that falls under recommending a product and the question should be closed.

Comment: No.  My real question is about the kind, the USB in particular because they're cheaper.  I want to see the encoded AM wave.  Can I do that with a USB scope?  Do I need an analog scope instead?  Do you think it would be better to just ask another question about RF and what scope type to use?

Comment: the usb kind is cheaper initially because there is no display, no buttons, smaller package, less power.  is it also cheaper because its measurement and capture capabilities are not that good?  thats a separate question.  Asking what kind of scope to use is definitely asking for a recommendation which is one of the common close this question options.

Comment: the global non branded can usb or say ethernet based no display no buttons do as well as with display and buttons, absolutely can potentially meet or exceed because those things are not relevant to is measurement capabilities.

Comment: what you are really asking for is you want to buy something so unfortunately this is not the right place, you need to read reviews and filter through the normal good/real reviews from bogus ones from employees or competitors.  or you just have to buy one, get or make a circuit that you believe is good and examine it and see how the scope does.  if at work or school or a maker space you can find a high end one you can compare.

Comment: This is somewhat misleading.  Cheap USB scopes are bad scopes, irrespective of their lack of screens.  Cheap scopes with a normal sized screen are halfway ok, because they compete in a tight market against others that are.

Answer (score 1):

A USB scope can theoretically be just as good or better than a benchtop with one exception for safety.

Benchtops tend to be built better with lower noise and larger voltage thresholds, but that's not always true. USB tends to have the advantage on software, analysis, and storage. As long as the USB scope is cheaper only because it doesn't need a full hardware interface, it should be just as capable.

The only feature a benchtop will always have over USB is grounding. Not in terms of signal integrity. More for **if you screw up.**

Unless you get a floating scope or exclusively use active differential probes, the passive probe ground lead is coupled right to earth. With USB, that's right through your computer's motherboard and power supply. The one time you slip or aren't thinking could fry both your scope and your computer.

Other than that, it's purely a question of specs, features, and user interface. Don't forget to include your computer's specs into that equation if you go USB.

Comment: In theorey, yes.  In practice the cheap USB scopes have deficient architecture.  The ones with comparable performance cost as much or more than that performance with a screen.

Comment: @ChrisStratton No argument there. If you want performance, you'll have to pay. A cheap USB scope has the same likelihood of being crap as a cheap benchtop. The question was about the ability of USB scopes to measure RF, which ultimately has nothing inherently to do with USB. I didn't address price or the real implied question of "what's the cheapest scope I can use for this project" because that gets into product reviews and shopping recommendations.

Comment: No, "the same likelihood of being crap" is a mistaken conclusion.  What you're not aware of is that cheap USB scopes have entirely different architecture from even the lowest end of bench scopes with normal sized screens - **it's not the screen that is the main thing missing** to reduce cost.  Those that have a normal scope architecture are not cheaper than traditional scopes of comparable performance (if anything, more expensive).  Those that don't have a normal scope architecture horribly underperform.